# How to diagnose/fix network congestion?

Tags: networking, router

After battling with packet loss (noticeable in Zoom calls, etc.) and switching ISPs, I've decided to do a short test and saw that the packet loss occurs at different times on different machines, but within a couple of seconds from each other.

(e.g. Zoom on machine 1 loses packets for 2 seconds, machine 2 is fine.
Three seconds later machine 1 is fine, machine 2 starts losing packets)

Is this a sign of network congestion? Is it some other hardware/router problem? There seems to be plenty of bandwidth available, and no torrents or any other network hogging programs are running anywhere on the network.

Comment: When switching ISPs, did you also switch modems/routers?

Comment: Same infrastructure & router, only swapped ISPs since I figured it wasn't the issue (or so I thought, and it's the only one with higher speeds in my neighborhood)

Comment: Try to factory reboot the router, and if this doesn't help then look for a firmware update.

Comment: Zoom congestion is affected by other people on the Zoom call. We see this fairly often. See if your congestion is also evident on other sites.

Comment: The time of day also matters. It's more than likely zoom hasn't caught up & updated their infrastructure with the explosion of new users. It's zoom, not your equipment or ISP. Use google Hangouts if it annoys you...